# Typescript - Dynamic array of variables and types

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I make this bind function but I want to make it more dynamic. Here I'm searching for the specific attribute "Geo" becuase this is also a class "Geo" object. But i need an array from the variables that are not string. Here the only variable that is not string (or number maybe) is the geo". I need the viariable name and the type "Geo"

```
import { Geo } from "./geo";
export class Address {
  city: string;
  geo: Geo;
  street: string;
  suite: string;
  zipcode: string;

  public static bind(address) {

    for (var propertyName in address) {
      // I want here an array
      if (propertyName === 'geo') {
        address.geo = Geo.bind(address.geo);
      }
    }
    return Object.assign(new Address(), address);
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to classify objects by their `constructor` or just retrieve instances of the `Geo`?

Comment: the main puspose it to take a json array an recursively change simple object to class object. so if the address has a property geo with type Geo i want to change the object to geo object

Comment: OK, well JSON values can be one of `string`, `number`, `boolean`, `null`, `{}`, and `[]`. You seem to be going off of the name of the property, mapping to its type, but that is not generalizable to all domain models. More to the point what are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: this is typescript... so yes i can give type to a property. geo: Geo is acceptable

Comment: No, that is where you are mistaken and why I removed the TypeScript specific tags from the question. TypeScript types exist only at compile time. They are erased from the emitted JavaScript. TypeScript is for tooling support. Intellisense, API usage validation, static error detection.

Comment: ooooo... yes.... i forget this.... so i have to define a another variable with the fields i want to bind...  thanks... i totally forget this

Comment: What I would do if I needed type information client side is to make it part of the serialized payload created by the server. Then you could instantiate whatever objects you wished reliably. But I still don't think that is useful most of the time. The main reason is that it doesn't feel right for serialized objects to be given a bunch of behavior. That said, if you know what type you want to map and endpoint to, you can use a constructor or factory. I guess that is what `bind` is, it is a constructor, my Haskell is lousy :p

Comment: may be `instanceof` operator may help you? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof